# Selenium/NUnit run one test on multiple IP addresses

Tags: nunit, selenium, selenium-rc

I have a test suite DLL written in C# that uses Selenium.This is then loaded into NUnit and tests can be performed on our embedded web server boards.

Does anyone know how to run a NUnit Selenium test on multiple IPs in multiple browsers?

I have tried creating multiple DefaultSelenium classes but they point to the same Internet Explorer window.  I need multiple instances of the Selenium RC controlling individual Internet Explorer windows.

Have been looking a lot on the Selenium User Group and in various documentation but can find a definitive answer.

Cheers,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you want to be using Selenium Grid and then have a mechanism for passing in different Browsers and use something like PNunit to run the tests